# Is installing programs from cmd.exe safe?

Tags: cmd.exe

I sometimes have issues installing security software, such as ESET or MS EMET using their installers, usually a permissions thing, so I resort to opening a command prompt as admin (instead of running around error codes with no documentation) and just using for example c:\eset\install.exe, which everytime results in no issues.

Someone said to me however that I shouldn't be doing it, though I couldn't understand what he was saying. Mainly that it isn't "safe". So it spooked me a little.

So is it fine to do? Is it any different at all to say right clicking the installer and clicking run as administrator?

Sorry for this kind of question, but there is this tiny thing in my mind that made me question it, that if the install fails but succeds in cmd.exe, what is cmd.exe doing differently? From what I can tell, cmd.exe just runs the install.exe as admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as going to the program, right-click -> Run as Administrator.

The only difference is that, since you run the command prompt as administrator already, you are not receiving any following popup that notifies you a program needs administrator access.

So assuming you first try to install the program without your workaround, get errors then try again using the administrative privileges, and you know that the program is save, there's no real problem here.

But if you just always work this way, yes, then it can be a problem. An administrator has a lot more rights when past the UAC prompt, so if you like use a CMD prompt as administrator as a default work environment because you still had it open, and accidentally start a malicious program, your best virus scanner won't protect you from that.